# How to make use mod_rewrite to create pretty permalinks for a custom-built CMS PHP script meant for external distribution?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to build a CMS that will be used by other people, which means that I can't rely on editing the .htaccess files for mdo_rewrite. I have looked up methods for mod rewriting urls from `http://example.com/index.php?category=food` to `http://example.com/category/food` but most of them seem to rely on apache and editing the .htaccess file, which would only work if you are creating a script which, like public scripts like Wordpress, rely on being installed on an external user's server. How do I mod_rewrite from within the script so that the script either automatically edits the user's mod_rewrite settings in .htaccess (as in altering the rewrite rule in the file from within the script itself) or some other method that would work fo a CMS script that is solely written in PHP and intended to be used on another server.

Answer (score 0):

If the script you are using, is making use of a popular framework, chances are they have installed a so called "routing" system inside the framework. That by itself allows nice URLs.

In fact, if you're using any commercial script for a webshop or something alike, they probably have a mod, plugin or component that allows nice URLs. Look it up or add additional info please. :-).

Comment: I am not using a script but building a script (sorry, should've clarified this a little better) so it's not making use of a framework.

Comment: In that case, lookup "routing". I believe CodeIgniter (although maybe not the best choice for a framework) has a decent routing system.

Comment: Oh, its also a basic principle in most MVC (Model, View, Controller) based systems, to have routing. So anything that points to something like that, take a look!

Comment: I've looked it up but it seems like it would still require redirecting to a php file via the .htaccess. Like if you put the routing code in index.php you have to redirect to index.php or something.

Comment: Well yes, but you can than use just 1 .htaccess file for all versions of your system, without alterations. That makes routing using only PHP possible. I'm afraid there's no other way to get what you're looking for.